# syntax error, unexpected 'fwrite' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, fwrite

Can someone check my code, I don't know what's wrong with it. Whenever I execute the code, I get that error in the title.

```
<?php
$file = "newfile.txt";

$text = "This is a text line. ";

$handle = fopen($file, "w");

fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);

$handle = fopen($file, "a");

$text = "Here are more text lines to insert."
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);

include ($file);

?>
```

Comment: I did the same mistake and luckily found this question here ;) +1 from myside.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot a ; right after this line:

```
$text = "Here are more text lines to insert."
```

This will fix your problem.